# Is there any lib support writing graphQL query and parsing response in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, graphql

I need to consume the [GraphQL](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/) API from a IOS app written in swift. Is there any client lib that support writing the query and parsing the response?
Facebook seems doesn't talk much about how they use it in their mobile app.

**Update 1**
(for the first -1 T.T)

I did searching around for couple of days and one of the best lib I could found is [Chester](https://github.com/JanGorman/Chester). This lib just help build the query string only and do nothing regarding the schema. I didn't hope that there will be a feature complete lib for Swift but really hope that some one could point me to the similar one for a non-scripting, strong typed language.

Comment: We haven't yet release it but soon there will be a proper Swift GraphQL client: https://github.com/graphcool/ios-graphql-client

Comment: Can wait to see that! Could you spoil a little bit about how could we write GraphQL query (no multiple line literal is annoying T.T) and will it support auto generating model code?

Comment: @schickling any news on this?

Comment: https://github.com/apollostack/apollo-ios

Answer (score 0):

try GQLSwiftQuery

```
    let inputArgs = [
        "restaurantId": "\(self.restaurantId)",
        "input":
    ]



    let fullQuery = GQLQuery(
        withSchemaType: .Mutation,
        withQueryTitle: "createDish",
        withQueryArguments:inputArgs as! [String : AnyObject],
        withQueryItems: ["id"]

    )
```

//        let myQuery = fullQuery.queryString
//        let removedEquals = myQuery.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("=", withString: ":")
//        let query = removedEquals.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(";", withString: ",")
//        print(query)
//

```
   print(fullQuery.queryString)

    let parameters = ["query": fullQuery.queryString]
```